# Ubuntu: perl: undefined symbol: PL_perl_destruct_level

Tags: perl, apt-get, ubuntu-12.04

Recently, I tried to crosscompile Perl on my Ubuntu system but made a mistake. The finished binary was installed on my productive system besides the already present perl version. Ever since I get the following error when running a perl script:

```
/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/perl: undefined symbol: PL_perl_destruct_level
```

Of course I removed my version but the problem persists and the error event appears when I try to reinstall perl with apt-get install --reinstall perl.

Could anybody help me fixing this problem and save my Ubuntu from reinstallation?

Cheers,
Anonymous Coward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem by copying a perl-executable from an other installation and running

```
apt-get install --reinstall perl
```